# Merge multiple XML files of same structure into single xml in logic apps

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

1. From FTP server location my Logic App is fetching zip folder which can container **contains "N" no. of xml files of sample structure**
2. I am able to read content of xml files within for-each loop by parsing them into JSON

**3. Now at this point, I want my Logic App to merge the multiple xml files in JSON  into single xml file**

**Please suggest how can I implement above point #3.** *I have integration account to store mapping file.*

Input File 1: -

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<orderQuote>
    <order_id>AZS000001</order_id>
    <user_request>
        <app_user>
            <username>varunxxxxxxxxxxxx</username>
            <user_first_name>Varun</user_first_name>
            <user_last_name>Thakur</user_last_name>
            <user_email>varunthakur84@hotmail.com</user_email>          
        </app_user>

    </user_request>

    <quote_id>345678</quote_id>
    <rate_id>ABC001</rate_id>
  <contract_id>SR_ABC_XYZ</contract_id>
    <amendment_id>2019062401</amendment_id>
    <price> 10</price>
  <rate_effective_date>01-Jul-2019</rate_effective_date>
    <rate_expiration_date>30-Sep-2019</rate_expiration_date>
    <origin_trade></origin_trade>
    <destination_trade></destination_trade>
    <origin_city>Haiphong</origin_city>
    <origin_country>VIETNAM</origin_country>
    <destination_city>Atlanta</destination_city>
    <destination_country>USA</destination_country>
    <ordermentType>XYZ</ordermentType>
    <ordermentSize>XYZ</ordermentSize>
    <ordermentSizeType>DC</ordermentSizeType>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <order_dt>17-Sep-2019</order_dt>
    <customer>CompanyName RM Team</customer>
    <quote_creation_dt>17-Sep-2019</quote_creation_dt>

</orderQuote>
```

Input File 2: -

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<orderQuote>
    <order_id>AZS000001</order_id>
    <user_request>
        <app_user>
            <username>varunxxxxxxxxxxxx</username>
            <user_first_name>Varun</user_first_name>
            <user_last_name>Thakur</user_last_name>
            <user_email>varunthakur84@hotmail.com</user_email>          
        </app_user>

    </user_request>

    <quote_id>8975545</quote_id>
    <rate_id>ABC002</rate_id>
  <contract_id>SR_A83Z</contract_id>
    <amendment_id>20134362401</amendment_id>
  <price>60</price>
  <rate_effective_date>01-JAJ-2019</rate_effective_date>
    <rate_expiration_date>30-DEC-2019</rate_expiration_date>
    <origin_trade></origin_trade>
    <destination_trade></destination_trade>
    <origin_city>Haiphong</origin_city>
    <origin_country>VIETNAM</origin_country>
    <destination_city>Atlanta</destination_city>
    <destination_country>USA</destination_country>
    <ordermentType>XYZ</ordermentType>
    <ordermentSize>XYZ</ordermentSize>
    <ordermentSizeType>DC</ordermentSizeType>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <order_dt>17-Sep-2019</order_dt>
    <customer>CompanyName RM Team</customer>
    <quote_creation_dt>17-Sep-2019</quote_creation_dt>

</orderQuote>
```

Expected Output File

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<orderQuote>
  <order_id>AZS000001</order_id>
  <user_request>
    <app_user>
      <username>varunxxxxxxxxxxxx</username>
      <user_first_name>Varun</user_first_name>
      <user_last_name>Thakur</user_last_name>
      <user_email>varunthakur84@hotmail.com</user_email>
    </app_user>

  </user_request>

  <quotationCollection>
    <quotation>
      <quote_id>8975545</quote_id>
      <rate_id>ABC002</rate_id>
      <contract_id>SR_A83Z</contract_id>
      <amendment_id>20134362401</amendment_id>
      <price>60</price>
      <rate_effective_date>01-JAJ-2019</rate_effective_date>
      <rate_expiration_date>30-DEC-2019</rate_expiration_date>
      <origin_trade></origin_trade>
      <destination_trade></destination_trade>
      <origin_city>Haiphong</origin_city>
      <origin_country>VIETNAM</origin_country>
      <destination_city>Atlanta</destination_city>
      <destination_country>USA</destination_country>
      <ordermentType>XYZ</ordermentType>
      <ordermentSize>XYZ</ordermentSize>
      <ordermentSizeType>DC</ordermentSizeType>
      <currency>USD</currency>
      <order_dt>17-Sep-2019</order_dt>
      <customer>CompanyName RM Team</customer>
      <quote_creation_dt>17-Sep-2019</quote_creation_dt>
    </quotation>
    <quotation>
      <quote_id>345678</quote_id>
      <rate_id>ABC001</rate_id>
      <contract_id>SR_ABC_XYZ</contract_id>
      <amendment_id>2019062401</amendment_id>
      <price> 10</price>
      <rate_effective_date>01-Jul-2019</rate_effective_date>
      <rate_expiration_date>30-Sep-2019</rate_expiration_date>
      <origin_trade></origin_trade>
      <destination_trade></destination_trade>
      <origin_city>Haiphong</origin_city>
      <origin_country>VIETNAM</origin_country>
      <destination_city>Atlanta</destination_city>
      <destination_country>USA</destination_country>
      <ordermentType>XYZ</ordermentType>
      <ordermentSize>XYZ</ordermentSize>
      <ordermentSizeType>DC</ordermentSizeType>
      <currency>USD</currency>
      <order_dt>17-Sep-2019</order_dt>
      <customer>CompanyName RM Team</customer>
      <quote_creation_dt>17-Sep-2019</quote_creation_dt>
    </quotation>
  </quotationCollection>
</orderQuote>
```

Comment: Could you please share some examples of the multiple xml files in json which you want to merge into single xml file ? And share an example result(json or xml) you expect.

Comment: @HuryShen Thanks for responding. I have added sample files for your reference.

Comment: So you want the result file in json format or xml format ?

Comment: @HuryShen First preference is xml otherwise JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to merge a part of content of multiple xml(json) files and your example is complex, so I simplified them.

Your requirement equivalent to merge the xml file

```
<orderQuote>
    <order_id>AZS000001</order_id>
    <quote_id>345678</quote_id>
    <rate_id>ABC001</rate_id>
</orderQuote>
```

and

```
<orderQuote>
    <order_id>AZS000001</order_id>
    <quote_id>8975545</quote_id>
    <rate_id>ABC002</rate_id>
</orderQuote>
```

to

```
<orderQuote>
  <order_id>AZS000001</order_id>

  <quotationCollection>
    <quotation>
      <quote_id>8975545</quote_id>
      <rate_id>ABC002</rate_id>
    </quotation>
    <quotation>
      <quote_id>345678</quote_id>
      <rate_id>ABC001</rate_id>
    </quotation>
  </quotationCollection>
</orderQuote>
```

For this requirement, I initialize four variables at first(the variable "isFirstTime" is used to judge if it is the first loop in for each).
[image]

Then I connect to ftp and parse the xml file get from ftp to json format. 
[image]

Next, I set the variable value with "order_id"(in this step, you may need to set some other variables such as "username", "user_first_name".....)
[image]

Next step, I create a "if" condition to do different work.
[image]

At bottom of the "For each" loop, we need to set the variable "isFirstTime" to false.
[image]

After complete the "For each" loop, we have last two steps.
[image]
The expression of "fx concat(...)" is

```
concat(concat(concat(concat('{"orderQuote":{"order_id":"', variables('order_id')), '","quotationCollection":['), variables('jsonstring')), ']}}')
```

After that, we can get the result file in json format.

```
{
  "orderQuote": {
    "order_id": "AZS000001",
    "quotationCollection": [
      {
        "quotation": {
          "quote_id": "345678",
          "rate_id": "ABC001"
        }
      },
      {
        "quotation": {
          "quote_id": "8975545",
          "rate_id": "ABC002"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

By the way, we'd better to do some settings before we use "For each" loop, click the "…" icon beside the "For each" action --> click "Settings" and then enable "Concurrency Control" and change the "Degree of Parallelism" to 1.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is helpful. Is it possible to implement the same without converting XML to JSON ?

Comment: Hi @Varun05, as far as I know, we can just do this operation by converting xml to json, or we can write the code to do this operation. By the way, if this solution helps your problem, could you please mark my answer as accepted, thanks~